# Error running Testnet node: unwrapEnvelopeErr = ObsoleteNodeCHAIN BlockNo 2989599 SlotNo 39614381

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I am trying to run a testnet node (version 1.29) but it stops sync with this error:

```
$ cardano-node run --topology testnet-topology.json \ 
  --database-path ~/cardano/db/ \
  --socket-path ~/cardano/db/node.socket \ 
  --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
  --port 3001 \ 
  --config testnet-config.json
```

```
[danicuki:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:109] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.61 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt End, destination 52.58.117.45:3001 outcome: ConnectSuccess
[danicuki:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Notice:112] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.62 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Connection Attempt End, destination 3.128.220.55:3001 outcome: ConnectSuccessLast
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.62 UTC] IP 54.250.11.33:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.62 UTC] IP 18.132.238.21:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.62 UTC] IP 18.159.64.253:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.62 UTC] IP 54.241.77.32:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Notice:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:29.63 UTC] IP 54.151.49.138:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendConsumer (Just (ConnectionExceptionTrace (SubscriberError {seType = SubscriberParallelConnectionCancelled, seMessage = "Parallel connection cancelled", seStack = []}))) 1s
[danicuki:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:112] [2021-10-13 16:48:30.29 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 3.128.220.55:3001 HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 39614475, blockPointHash = 1acb3ab3338115eb485e8ae73e8abc24b2c48f2ddb4880bd85ca586aa6dcfd5b})) (HeaderEnvelopeError (OtherHeaderEnvelopeError (HardForkEnvelopeErrFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapEnvelopeErr {unwrapEnvelopeErr = ObsoleteNodeCHAIN 6 5})))))))) (Tip (SlotNo 39614381) 809a09ac9273bf7c468622c0f6f480deb8f81946c4381e7dbdf1aae63195c678 (BlockNo 2984847)) (Tip (SlotNo 39774427) bd48afea977bc086e9329a6de76ce094ff20c0a960c6e9e7e761c4322d6e3392 (BlockNo 2989605))
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:30.29 UTC] IP 3.128.220.55:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 39614475, blockPointHash = 1acb3ab3338115eb485e8ae73e8abc24b2c48f2ddb4880bd85ca586aa6dcfd5b})) (HeaderEnvelopeError (OtherHeaderEnvelopeError (HardForkEnvelopeErrFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapEnvelopeErr {unwrapEnvelopeErr = ObsoleteNodeCHAIN 6 5})))))))) (Tip (SlotNo 39614381) 809a09ac9273bf7c468622c0f6f480deb8f81946c4381e7dbdf1aae63195c678 (BlockNo 2984847)) (Tip (SlotNo 39774427) bd48afea977bc086e9329a6de76ce094ff20c0a960c6e9e7e761c4322d6e3392 (BlockNo 2989605))))) 200s 200s
[danicuki:cardano.node.DnsSubscription:Error:109] [2021-10-13 16:48:30.58 UTC] Domain: "relays-new.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io" Application Exception: 52.58.117.45:3001 HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 39614475, blockPointHash = 1acb3ab3338115eb485e8ae73e8abc24b2c48f2ddb4880bd85ca586aa6dcfd5b})) (HeaderEnvelopeError (OtherHeaderEnvelopeError (HardForkEnvelopeErrFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapEnvelopeErr {unwrapEnvelopeErr = ObsoleteNodeCHAIN 6 5})))))))) (Tip (SlotNo 39614381) 809a09ac9273bf7c468622c0f6f480deb8f81946c4381e7dbdf1aae63195c678 (BlockNo 2984847)) (Tip (SlotNo 39774427) bd48afea977bc086e9329a6de76ce094ff20c0a960c6e9e7e761c4322d6e3392 (BlockNo 2989605))
[danicuki:cardano.node.ErrorPolicy:Warning:52] [2021-10-13 16:48:30.58 UTC] IP 52.58.117.45:3001 ErrorPolicySuspendPeer (Just (ApplicationExceptionTrace (HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 39614475, blockPointHash = 1acb3ab3338115eb485e8ae73e8abc24b2c48f2ddb4880bd85ca586aa6dcfd5b})) (HeaderEnvelopeError (OtherHeaderEnvelopeError (HardForkEnvelopeErrFromEra S (S (S (S (Z (WrapEnvelopeErr {unwrapEnvelopeErr = ObsoleteNodeCHAIN 6 5})))))))) (Tip (SlotNo 39614381) 809a09ac9273bf7c468622c0f6f480deb8f81946c4381e7dbdf1aae63195c678 (BlockNo 2984847)) (Tip (SlotNo 39774427) bd48afea977bc086e9329a6de76ce094ff20c0a960c6e9e7e761c4322d6e3392 (BlockNo 2989605))))) 200s 200s
```

My configs are downloaded from this source:

```
https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/testnet-config.json
https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/testnet-byron-genesis.json
https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/testnet-shelley-genesis.json
https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/testnet-alonzo-genesis.json
https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/cardano-node/cardano-deployment/latest-finished/download/1/testnet-topology.json
```

What is wrong with my configs?

Comment: Before trying anything else have you tried using cardano-node 1.30.1?

Answer (score 4):

The solution for this problem is to download the latest version of cardano-node. 1.29 is broken for testnet, but the 1.30.1 works perfectly.

Download here:
(https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7739444)

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!